# How to read JSON response with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to read response with jQuery and I have no idea how it works with response.

See the small example code with js post + response here:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/ajaxpost/ajax.php",
    type: "post",   
    data: "action=check&uid=1",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        $("#result").html('submitted successfully');
        response = JSON.parse(data);
        status = response.status;
        alert(status); 
    },
    error:function(){
        $("#result").html('there is error while submit');
    }   
});
```

Response is:

```
{"first":"John","last":"Heyden","uid":"1","token":"10","value":"100000","friends":"23","country":"australia","status":"online"}
```

Now what I want in this is to `alert online`

Can someone tell me what I am missing in this?

---

When I remove **dataType: "json",** this works fine

```
success: function(data){
    $("#result").html('submitted successfully');
    var r = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    alert(r.status);
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to parse `data`? I think this should be a javascript object already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to parse response as the dataType is set as json, the method will parse the response to json ans will pass it to the handler

just

```
alert(data.status)
```

Ex:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/ajaxpost/ajax.php",
    type: "post",   
    data: "action=check&uid=1",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        $("#result").html('submitted successfully');
        status = data.status;
        alert(status); 
    },
    error:function(){
        $("#result").html('there is error while submit');
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do

```
alert(data.status);   // online
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your parsing method there. Since you're using jQuery, try:

```
var r = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
alert(r.status);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you defined the `dataType` as json you don't need to parse it, it will be converted to object for you, so just do:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/ajaxpost/ajax.php",
    type: "post",   
    data: "action=check&uid=1",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        $("#result").html('submitted successfully');
        //Don't need this line 
        //response = JSON.parse(data);
       //you called the object data, so use it
        status = data.status;
        alert(status); 
    },
    error:function(){
        $("#result").html('there is error while submit');
    }   
});
```